# Printing text based on the position of a button

Tags: android, button, printing, position

I have a SlidingDrawer menu in my app, and when the drawer is open I want the name for each button on the drawer to display as the buttons go pass it.

Do you all have any ideas to whether this is possible or not? I have been searching for about an hour and I can't find any answers.

Comment: Putting up buttons in SlidingDrawer is possible. Is this what you are looking for? If yes, show some more code or an image of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood what you want correctly (adding text from the drawer on top of buttons on the main layout) you can try this. I don't know how accurate it would be:

Place the sliding drawer as the topmost element in your layout with a transparent background.

Use exactly the same layout you're using for your "main" layout (where the buttons are) and use a textView where your buttons are.

When your sliding drawer opens, the text from its content will appear on top of the button

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was to vauge. Here is exactly what I want to happen:    There is an invisible text box a little above and directly to the left of the button that opens the SlidingDrawer. When the sliding drawer is  opened, each button will pass the textView and when it does the textView displays the name of the button. So if a picture of a camera goes by the text box, the textbox will says Pictures.

Comment: Sorry, no idea.
Try looking at the source code of SlidingDrawer and see if you can implement something like that by extending it.